# AVCaptureSession settings of Low, Medium and High, what res do they each represent?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

My app records videos, and I use settings to set the quality to record at.
I was wondering if anybody knows what resolution they each represent?

Low seems to be tiny and pretty worthless.

While high seems to be really high res and file sizes of these recordings are quite high.

```
if (appDelegate.vidRes == 1)
{
    NSLog(@"******   >>>>> SETTING VIDEO RES TO LOW <<<<<   *******");
    [session setSessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPresetLow];
}
else if (appDelegate.vidRes == 2)
{
    NSLog(@"******   >>>>> SETTING VIDEO RES TO MED <<<<<   *******");
    [session setSessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"******   >>>>> SETTING VIDEO RES TO HIGH <<<<<   *******");
    [session setSessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];
}
```

I would like to find some nice alternatives to Low, which is too low quality. And High which is too high quality.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
Preset                          3G       3GS    4 back      4 front

AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh    400x304  640x480  1280x720    640x480
AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium  400x304  480x360  480x360     480x360
AVCaptureSessionPresetLow     400x306  192x144  192x144     192x144
AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   NA     640x480  640x480     640x480
AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  NA       NA     1280x720    NA
AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     NA       NA     NA          NA
```

Source: http://cmgresearch.blogspot.com/2010/10/augmented-reality-on-iphone-with-ios40.html

The following table includes newer devices, source is [Method to find device's camera resolution iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422322/method-to-find-devices-camera-resolution-ios#31964333)

```
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
|        Device         |    Camera    |     AVCaptureSessionPreset      |  Resolution   |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPhone 4S             | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | not supported |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 3264x2448     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPhone 5/5C/5S/6/6+   |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 1280x960      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 3264x2448     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPhone 6S/6S          |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT camera |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 1280x960      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK camera  |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 4032x3024     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPad 2                |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | not supported |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 960x720       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPad 3                |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | not supported |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 2592x1936     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPad 4/Air            |              |                                 |               |
| iPad Mini 1/2/3       |              |                                 |               |
| iPod 5G               |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 1280x960      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 2592x1936     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPad Air 2            |              |                                 |               |
| iPad Mini 4           |              |                                 |               |
| iPad Pro              |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 1280x960      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 3264x2448     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPod Touch 5          |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 1280x960      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 2592x1936     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPod Touch 6          |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 1280x960      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 3264x2448     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
```

To set your own resolution, you'll have to log the data in AVCaptureSessionPreset, check what kind of class is it and how to simulate such data, then type in the data yourself.