# Method to find device's camera resolution iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture

Whats the best method to find the image resolution going to be captured using setting `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`.
I am trying to find the resolution before capturing the image.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the function below, you can programmatically get the resolution from `activeFormat` before capture begins, though not before adding inputs and outputs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/activeFormat

```
private func getCaptureResolution() -> CGSize {
    // Define default resolution
    var resolution = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)

    // Get cur video device
    let curVideoDevice = useBackCamera ? backCameraDevice : frontCameraDevice

    // Set if video portrait orientation
    let portraitOrientation = orientation == .Portrait || orientation == .PortraitUpsideDown

    // Get video dimensions
    if let formatDescription = curVideoDevice?.activeFormat.formatDescription {
        let dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(formatDescription)
        resolution = CGSize(width: CGFloat(dimensions.width), height: CGFloat(dimensions.height))
        if portraitOrientation {
            resolution = CGSize(width: resolution.height, height: resolution.width)
        }
    }

    // Return resolution
    return resolution
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant!

Comment: https://github.com/nateemma/FilterCam/blob/f3961a955b237441bb75403091776c1402eb08aa/FilterCam/Models/CameraManager.swift

Answer (score 113):

Here is the a table of all tested camera sessionPreset`s on devices, that support iOS 9

```
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
|        Device         |    Camera    |     AVCaptureSessionPreset      |  Resolution   |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPhone 4S             | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | not supported |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 3264x2448     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPhone 5/5C/5S/6/6+   |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 1280x960      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 3264x2448     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPhone 6S/6S          |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT camera |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 1280x960      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK camera  |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 4032x3024     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPad 2                |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | not supported |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 960x720       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPad 3                |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | not supported |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 2592x1936     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPad 4/Air            |              |                                 |               |
| iPad Mini 1/2/3       |              |                                 |               |
| iPod 5G               |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 1280x960      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 2592x1936     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPad Air 2            |              |                                 |               |
| iPad Mini 4           |              |                                 |               |
| iPad Pro              |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 1280x960      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 3264x2448     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPod Touch 5          |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 1280x960      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 2592x1936     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| iPod Touch 6          |              |                                 |               |
|                       | FRONT        |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 1280x960      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | not supported |
|                       | BACK         |                                 |               |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto     | 3264x2448     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      | 1920x1080     |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium    | 480x360       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPresetLow       | 192x144       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480   | 640x480       |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720  | 1280x720      |
|                       |              | AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 | 1920x1080     |
+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+---------------+
```

**CODE**

```
+ (NSDictionary*) cameraResolutions {
    NSString* deviceModel = [self deviceModel];

    // iPhone 4S
    if ([deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"]) {

        NSString* lFrontCam = @"640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSString* lBackCam = @"3264x2448,1920x1080,1280x720,640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSDictionary* lCamResolutions = @{@"front":lFrontCam,
                                          @"back":lBackCam};
        return lCamResolutions;
    }
    // iPhone 5/5C/5S/6/6+/iPod 6
    else if ([deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPod7,1"]) {

        NSString* lFrontCam = @"1280x960,1280x720,640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSString* lBackCam = @"3264x2448,1920x1080,1280x720,640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSDictionary* lCamResolutions = @{@"front":lFrontCam,
                                          @"back":lBackCam};
        return lCamResolutions;
    }
    // iPhone 6S/6S+
    else if ([deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"]) {
        NSString* lFrontCam = @"1280x960,1280x720,640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSString* lBackCam = @"4032x3024,1920x1080,1280x720,640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSDictionary* lCamResolutions = @{@"front":lFrontCam,
                                          @"back":lBackCam};
        return lCamResolutions;
    }
    // iPad 2
    else if ([deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"]) {


        NSString* lFrontCam = @"640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSString* lBackCam = @"1280x720,960x720,480x360,192x144,640x480";
        NSDictionary* lCamResolutions = @{@"front":lFrontCam,
                                          @"back":lBackCam};
        return lCamResolutions;
    }
    // iPad 3
    else if ([deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"]) {


        NSString* lFrontCam = @"640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSString* lBackCam = @"2592x1936,1920x1080,1280x720,640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSDictionary* lCamResolutions = @{@"front":lFrontCam,
                                          @"back":lBackCam};
        return lCamResolutions;
    }
    // iPad 4/Air/Mini/Mini 2/Mini 3/iPod 5G
    else if ([deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"]) {

        NSString* lFrontCam = @"1280x960,1280x720,640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSString* lBackCam = @"2592x1936,1920x1080,1280x720,640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSDictionary* lCamResolutions = @{@"front":lFrontCam,
                                           @"back":lBackCam};
        return lCamResolutions;
    }
    // iPad Air 2/Mini 4/Pro
    else if ([deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"]
             || [deviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"]) {
        NSString* lFrontCam = @"1280x960,1280x720,640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSString* lBackCam = @"3264x2448,1920x1080,1280x720,640x480,480x360,192x144";
        NSDictionary* lCamResolutions = @{@"front":lFrontCam,
                                          @"back":lBackCam};
        return lCamResolutions;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort ;)

Comment: Hi Roman, excellent work. Can you tell me how you got all this data?
Actually, I needed data for new iPhones(SE, 7, 7+, 8, 8+, X). I would really appreciate if you can update this list for new iPhones. Thanks

Comment: Hi Roman, Can you please provide a link or more info about your sources?

Answer (score 8):

There's probably no way to *directly* get the camera resolution programmatically *before* capturing an image.

Apple provides a table for various devices and presets:

[Capturing Still Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW30)

Comment: This is so sad! Ok, iOS8 is only supported by 8MP-devices. But still that would mean hardcoded values. And if the next device has a higher camera resolution, the app needs an instant update with new hardcoded values :(

Comment: @ecth You can programmatically get the resolution from `activeFormat` before capture begins, though not before adding inputs and outputs. Full answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done in this way:

```
/* Callback that is called when you activate the capture session. */
- (void) avCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
        CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = nil;
        NSArray *ports = [deviceInput ports];
        AVCaptureInputPort *usePort = nil;

        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in ports) {
                if (usePort == nil || [port.mediaType isEqualToString:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                        usePort = port;
                        break;
                }
        }

        if (usePort != nil)
                formatDescription = usePort.formatDescription;
        if (formatDescription != nil) {
                /*------------>>>>>>> THIS IS YOUR RESOLUTION */
                CMVideoDimensions dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(formatDescription);
                self.frameSize = CGSizeMake(dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
                NSLog(@"Capturing with %dx%d", (int)self.frameSize.width, (int)self.frameSize.height);
        } else {
                NSLog(@"Failed to detect resolution, using default one.");
                self.frameSize = CGSizeMake(640.0f, 480.0f);
        }
}

- (id) init {
        if ((self = [super init])) {
                /* Default framesize. */
                self.frameSize = CGSizeMake(640.0f, 480.0f);

                AVCaptureSession *capSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
                /* -------->>>>>>> REQUESTED RESOLUTION, CAN BE SOMTHING ELSE */
                [capSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];

//                if (([modelName rangeOfString:@"iPhone 5"].length != 0) || ([modelName rangeOfString:@"iPhone 6"].length != 0)) {
//                        [capSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];
//                } else {
//                        [capSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];
//                }
//                
                self.captureSession = capSession;

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(avCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification:)
                                                             name:AVCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification object:nil];
        }
        return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
        if (self.captureSession.isRunning)
                [self.captureSession stopRunning];
        self.captureSession = nil;
}

- (void) addRawViewOutput
{
    /* We setup the output */
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *captureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

        /* While a frame is processes in -captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: delegate methods
           no other frames are added in the queue.
       If you don't want this behaviour set the property to NO */
    captureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;

        /*We specify a minimum duration for each frame (play with this settings to avoid having too many frames waiting
     in the queue because it can cause memory issues). It is similar to the inverse of the maximum framerate.
     In this example we set a min frame duration of 1/10 seconds so a maximum framerate of 10fps. We say that
     we are not able to process more than 10 frames per second.*/
    //captureOutput.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 10);

    /*We create a serial queue to handle the processing of our frames*/
    dispatch_queue_t queue;
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.YourApp.cameraQueue", NULL);
    [captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
//  dispatch_release(queue);

    // Set the video output to store frame in BGRA (It is supposed to be faster)
    NSString *key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey;
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA];
    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key];
    [captureOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings];

        // Register an output
    [self.captureSession addOutput:captureOutput];
}

- (bool) startWithDevicePosition:(AVCaptureDevicePosition)devicePosition
{
        AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [self cameraWithPosition:devicePosition];

        if (!videoDevice)
                return FALSE;

        NSError *error;

        AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoIn = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error];
        self.deviceInput = videoIn;

        if (!error)
        {
                if ([[self captureSession] canAddInput:videoIn])
                {
                        [[self captureSession] addInput:videoIn];
                }
                else
                {
                        NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input");
                        return FALSE;
                }
        }
        else
        {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't create video input");
                return FALSE;
        }

        [self addRawViewOutput];
        [self resume];
        return TRUE;
}

-(void) pause
{
        self.paused = YES;
        if (self.captureSession.isRunning)
                [captureSession stopRunning];
}

-(void) resume
{
        if (!self.captureSession.isRunning)
                [captureSession startRunning];
        self.paused = NO;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark AVCaptureSession delegate
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

        /* Lock the image buffer */
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

        /* Get information about the image */
        uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
        size_t stride = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
        size_t size = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(imageBuffer);

        BGRAVideoFrame frame = {(int)width, (int)height, (int)stride, (int)size, baseAddress};
        [delegate frameReady:frame];

        /* We unlock the image buffer */
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for get maximum Image resolution for device cameras:

```
- (CMVideoDimensions) getCameraMaxStillImageResolution:(AVCaptureDevicePosition) cameraPosition {

    CMVideoDimensions max_resolution;
    max_resolution.width = 0;
    max_resolution.height = 0;

    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;

    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if ([device position] == cameraPosition) {
            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (captureDevice == nil) {
        return max_resolution;
    }

    NSArray* availFormats=captureDevice.formats;

    for (AVCaptureDeviceFormat* format in availFormats) {
        CMVideoDimensions resolution = format.highResolutionStillImageDimensions;
        int w = resolution.width;
        int h = resolution.height;
        if ((w * h) > (max_resolution.width * max_resolution.height)) {
            max_resolution.width = w;
            max_resolution.height = h;
        }
    }

    return max_resolution;
}

- (void) printCamerasInfo {
    CMVideoDimensions res;
    res = [self getCameraMaxStillImageResolution:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    NSLog(@" Back  Camera max Image resolution: %d x %d", res.width, res.height);
    res = [self getCameraMaxStillImageResolution:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];
    NSLog(@" Front Camera max Image resolution: %d x %d", res.width, res.height);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post [identical answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38907603) to [multiple questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38907612). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*