# OpenCV camera preview on iOS stretched

Tags: ios, opencv, camera

I've followed the documentation of OpenCV to [implement the camera preview](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/dc8/tutorial_video_processing.html). Here, CvVideoCamera is initialised with a `UIIamgeView`. I've now set the constraints of my UIImageView to fill out the whole screen.

The initialisation of the camera is as follows:

```
self.videoCamera = [[VideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView];
self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 30;
self.videoCamera.grayscaleMode = false;
self.videoCamera.delegate = self;

[self.videoCamera start];
```

I've also set the contentMode:
`[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill]`

Still, the camera preview is distorted:

[image: Distorted]

For comparison the in the camera app:

[image: correct aspect ratio]

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust `defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset` E.g.:

`self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;`

Here is the a table of all tested camera sessionPreset's on devices, that support iOS 9

[Method to find device's camera resolution iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422322/method-to-find-devices-camera-resolution-ios/31964333#31964333)