# AVFoundation capture a still Image too slowly

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I use `AVFoundation` to capture a still image, it will takes about 0.8 seconds. I think it's really slowly. But when I use the system's penter code hererimary camera, it's much more faster.

This is the function I used : it's really slowly, maybe there is something I don't know, can anyone help me?

```
- (void)captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection completionHandler:(void (^)(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error))handler;
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an issue with the resolution of your AVCaptureSession. If you set your sessionPreset to `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`, then that is the highest resolution photo from the camera which can be slow to parse.

Try setting your sessionPreset to `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`. On some devices, the resolution difference (amount of pixels in the photo) is nearly 50%! For a detailed table of device photo resolutions, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31964333/4769084