# How to know does an iphone device support triple-cameras system?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone

In my project, I am trying to support triple cameras system. But I don't know how to check whether a device has triple cameras?

Comment: You could identify the iPhone model (get hints on how to do here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422322/method-to-find-devices-camera-resolution-ios). And from there know if it has triple camera.

Comment: @claude31 No need to get that. It's often string based as well, which is a massive fail in itself :/

Answer (score 8):

you can do this with following code either device has builtin dual back camera or wide angle back camera

```
var currentDevice:AVCaptureDevice?
        if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
        {
            currentDevice = device
        }
        else if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInTripleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
        {
            currentDevice = device
        }
        else if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
        {
            currentDevice = device
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error: no camera available")
        }
```

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Does it means that a device support triple-camera system when type equals to builtInDualCamera,  builtInTripleCamera or builtInWideAngleCamera?

Answer (score 4):

In the AVFoundation kit you have an AVCaptureDevice, which have an DeviceType which you can put as the default.

```swift
if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInTripleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
            
}
```