# Detect iPhone cameras on in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, camera

How can I detect which cameras are available on the iPhone so I can present the same icons for .5 1x 2x 3x (assuming it's an iPhone 14 Pro Max in this case) as Apple does in their app?

I can see how to discover the cameras, such as builtInWideAngleCamera, builtInTelephotoCamera, etc. but how do I know what the zoom is on each one? Now the iPhone 15 Pro Max has 5x too.

Basically what I want to do is replicate the buttons in Apple's camera app? Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks

Comment: this answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/31964333/2583598

Comment: This finds the resolution but not the level of zoom